# MongoDb need id to each element

Tags: mongodb

here is the json representation of one mongodb record

```
{
  _id : ObjectId("4e77bb3b8a3e000000004f7a"),
  when : Date("2011-09-19T02:10:11.3Z",
  author : "alex",
  title : "No Free Lunch",
  text : "This is the text of the post.  It could be very long.",
  tags : [ "business", "ramblings" ],
  votes : 5,
  voters : [ "jane", "joe", "spencer", "phyllis", "li" ],
  comments : [
    { who : "jane", when : Date("2011-09-19T04:00:10.112Z"),
      comment : "I agree." },
    { who : "meghan", when : Date("2011-09-20T14:36:06.958Z"),
      comment : "You must be joking.  etc etc ..." }
  ]
}
```

now i have a problem that if i want to delete any of comment from `comments` array than how can i do that ?

i don't want to rely on comment text.

is there any facility that give id to each and every object in document.

Comment: No, MongoDB, gives an id only to a document. For having an id for an object in your array, you have to do it on your own.

Comment: i want this by using java and if i add id to every element by own than i want to code more for managing that ids. you know any nosql db that fulfill my criteria?.

Comment: _id is the **id** of the object

Comment: No however provided you use functions which do not trigger a resort of your array (like `$push` etc) then you could use the array position ids, i.e. 0 and 1 for the first and second position.

Comment: in my scenario someone can add a comment , and also delete that comment so i have to keep a unique identifier which used as a _id.

Comment: What is your real problem? You want to remove a particular comment from the comments array???

Comment: What have you tried so far? The documentation of MongoDB is very extensive about array manipulation. There are even enough Stackoverflow question dealing with array manipulation in MongoDB. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Always mention what you are using clearly, you are looking for a java answer is mentioned nowhere

Comment: how you know which comment should be removed? I mean, are you  planning to use the index, the name?

Answer (score 1):

_id field will be automatically added to the top level documents when not populated during the document insertion.  When you have sub-documents, it is based on your application need and you have to design such that, you should be able to point that sub-document by some means.

For your case, we can probably use the comment_id field which can be used to identify your sub-document uniquely for various operations on them later (if you need to).

Hope this helps!